# Hard shadows with path/ bi-directional path tracing

Tags: graphics, raytracing

I am implementing the bi-directional path tracing algorithm (using pbrt as a source), but am seeing very hard shadows with a cornell box case that I have set up.

Here is how the rendered result looks like,

[image: Cornell box case with light occluded from all sides]

The light source can be thought of as a thin box, with only one side emitting light. All other five sides act as occluders.

I would expect to see more in the dark areas (if you look closely, there is a sphere in the room). This specific output is from `s == 1`, that would equate to regular path tracing, and was generated with 100 samples/ pixel . The output from `s == 0` looks even darker, with just one bright spot on the ceiling.

Any ideas why this may be happening? The shadows seem to be in the right place, but the lighting contributions seem too low.

Comment: what happens when you make the light source brighter?

Comment: The light source brightness is already set to max, i.e., 1 (on a scale of 0-1).

Comment: In nature, light can be arbitrarily bright - why are you limiting it?

Comment: You are probably confusing the color with the intensity of the light. Intensity can be greater than 1 while the diffuse/specular color should be in the range 0-1.